# Does a Linux handbook exist?

Tags: linux, documentation

I want to learn about Linux.  I saw FreeBSD have Handbook which is awesome, is there such a project for Linux?

Currently im using OpenSuse.  I looked at their docs, but found nothing similiar.

Comment: Here are the official openSUSE docs for the past few releases... http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Official_documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[An Introduction to Linux](http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/index.html) from the [Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/) may be what you are looking for.  Various distributions also have distribution specific documentation such as the [Debian Documentation](http://www.debian.org/doc/). For openSUSE, I would start with the [Documentation Portal](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Documentation).

Documentation for Linux is extensive and covers a lot of areas.  There are many documents targeted for specific user groups such as users migrating from Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the useful links, "An Introduction to Linux" and Debian reference looks great!